# Обновления локации фрейма

Tags: php

Можно ли как то обновлять этот фрейм:

```
<FRAME SRC="<?php echo $row['loc']; ?>" NAME="_location" SCROLLING="AUTO" FRAMEBORDER=0>
```

?

Я имею ввиду, можно ли сделать что-то похожие на это:

```
<body onload="FRAME()">
```

Comment: да, но с использованием JS а не php

Comment: Есть куча вариантов, как обновить страницу. Вы что имеете в виду?

Comment: я имею ввиду чтоб вот это часть: SRC="<?php echo $row['loc']; ?>" Постоянно обновлялась, тоисть если поменялось значения $row['loc'] то чтоб изменения вступило в силу, не нужно было обновлять самому страницу...

Comment: `$row['loc']` генерируется еще до отображения страницы, а после отображения теряется. Если хотите получить ответ, объясните русским языком, что должно получиться, не используя технические термины.

Comment: Хорошо, я делаю браузерную игру, и локация у пользователя постоянно меняется, что нужно сделать чтоб она когда менялось еще и выводилась?

Comment: AJAX. 

Делаешь запрос на сервер при определенных условиях, точнее от определенных действий пользователя на странице.

Посылаешь на сервак данные, он их получает, что-то с ними делает, ну и отдает их обратно в каком-то формате, а дальше обновляй на странице что тебе нужно с новыми параметрами.